# How do I use sql query that is in a column in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below you will be able to see that I have the table 'sql_script', which has two columns 'ID' and 'Script'. These columns have three rows of data. The data is in column 'script' is again `SQL` queries. My problem is that I can not take these `SQL` queries into a new query based on the selection of `ID` in to the same query.

```
Select * from sql_script
```

Results :

```
ID        Script
1      Select * from test1
2      Select * from test2
3      Select * from test3
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It does not work this way. You are giving suggestions and were are improving and helping with them.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). It really will help if you told us why you think you need to do this.

Comment: You may be looking for a `join`. Simply put, joins allow you to include records new tables from results you have already found.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a great approach to store queries like this in your database. In order to do something like this you will need to use dynamic sql. Do you want to simply execute each query in succession?

You could do something like this:

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + Script + ';'
from sql_script
order by ID

select @SQL

--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

When you are satisfied just uncomment the exec line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can wrap it in execute_sql

```
 execute_sql(SELECT Script FROM sql_script WHERE Id=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)

select top 1 @query = script
from tbl

exec(@query)
```